# Java - Restrict Generics to Built-In/Immutable Types (Integer, Short, etc)?

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a container class, and the requirements for this code stipulate that (A) I should use generics, and (B) I should only allow it to accept the built-in wrapper classes (like Integer, Short, Double, etc).

That is to say, I want to be able to use things things like:

```
MyContainer<Integer>
MyContainer<Double>
```

But this kind of stuff should not be allowed:

```
MyContainer<MyClass1>
MyContainer<MyClass2>
```

---

Through my research into this topic I've found stuff like:

```
public class MyContainer<T extends (???)>
```

which leads me to wonder: do all the built-in wrappers extend a common class that I could specify in this way to make this work?

Alternatively, is there any way to make a generic only accept a defined list of classes? That would likely be a better option since that way the generic type couldn't be fooled by a user-defined class that extends the common interface, but I'm not sure it's possible to do that (?).

Comment: No, the closest is Comparable, but `Date` is `Comparable`

Answer (score 5):

> Alternatively, is there any way to make a generic only accept a
>   defined list of classes?

No, there is no such feature.

The generic bounds provide a restriction on the type hierarchy. For example, for built-in numeric types, the common ancestor is `Number`. But you can't prevent anyone from creating their own `Number` subclass and using that with your container class.

You're out of luck with generics. Consider using a factory which provides a pre-built container type for the built-in types you care about and throws an exception for any other type.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`java.lang.Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), per the Javadoc link,

> **Direct Known Subclasses:**
>
> ```
>   AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, 
>   Integer, Long, Short
> ```

Which does include your wrapper types. Of course, it includes a few more. It also doesn't prevent a user from extending Number too. So no, I don't think it's possible without using a generic `T` and checking the class at runtime.

Comment: AtomicInteger and AtomicLong are not immutable of course. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Even if they were a user could extend Number with a mutable type. So it doesn't seem like OP can have it.

Comment: If the `const` keyword did something, then maybe.

Comment: `final` just makes the reference immutable, not what it is pointing to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know. You said const. Which is reserved along with goto. If `const` did something (and presumably different from `final`) but ... what exactly?

Comment: In C++ an object addressed via `const` cannot be changed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes. And that "concept" is what "final" does (sort of, in the same way that generics are template types). So, if Java did C++ style const... well yeah that'd probably do it.